# How to test styled-components attribute with React-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I tried to write a unit test for my react-components, so the first step is to test the initial value of a styled-components attribute ,like below, so the function is when user click on a button the slideIndex state will change ,then it will trigger my slide change to another slide, so I want to test slideIndex's initial , and after I fire the button , will the index change to see if it's working.

```js
<Wrapper data-testid="wrapper" index={slideIndex}>
  {sliderItems.map((item) => {
    return (
      <Slide bg={item.bg} key={item.id}>
        <ImgContainer>
          <Image src={item.img} />
        </ImgContainer>
        <InfoContainer>
          <Title>{item.title}</Title>
          <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
          <Button>SHOW NOW</Button>
        </InfoContainer>
      </Slide>
    );
  })}
</Wrapper>;
```

But right now I stuck at testing if the index exist, here's my test code

```js
test('Check render wrapper inital index value to be 0', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Slider/>);
  const wrapperCom = getByTestId("wrapper")

  expect(wrapperCom).toHaveAttribute("index",0)
});
```

This will return

```
Expected the element to have attribute:
    index
Received:
    null
```

So I assume something went wrong , or that's not the right way to test this attribute?

Edit , I used index props like followings

```js
interface WrapperProp{
    index:number;
}
const Wrapper = styled.div<WrapperProp>`
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    /* transform: translateX(100vw); */
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transform: translateX(${(p)=>p.index * -100}vw);
```

Comment: Ultimately, the `getByTestId` query will return a DOM element, not the React component that generated it. How is `index` being used inside `Wrapper`, can you share the code for that component?

Comment: @juliomalves I edit the post and update the code of components, maybe you can  see what's the problem ?

Comment: You're not using `index` as an attribute, you use it to determine the `div`'s `translateX` value. Try checking for that instead.

Comment: @juliomalves I use expect(wrapperCom).toHaveStyle("transform: translateX(100vw)") and it works , so I  find this document with example  and I understand the difference better https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a document that gives a lot of detail on how to use "tohave..." function https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute,

and it turned out as juliomalves mentioned I used toHaveAttribute in wrong way , and I fixed it by following code, hope this will help.

```js
test('Check render wrapper inital translate style value', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Slider/>);
  const wrapperCom = getByTestId("wrapper")

  expect(wrapperCom).toHaveStyle("transform: translateX(100vw)")
  
});
```